# Absorption laws in Boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

Does anyone know how to prove the absorption laws in Boolean algebra?

i.e.

$$x + (x * y) = x$$

$$x * (x + y) = x$$

Thankyou so much

Comment: To clarify, you are using the symbols $+$ and $*$ to mean "or" and "and" respectively, correct?

Comment: What's your definition of Boolean algebra?

Comment: yes it is @KyleHansen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you believe in *identity* $(x*1 = x)$, the *distributive* property $(x*(x+y) = x*x + x*y)$, and *annulment* $(x+1 = 1)$, you may prove it like this:

$$\begin{align}
x+(x*y) &&\\
= (x*1)+(x*y) && \text{(identity)}\\
= x*(y+1) && \text{(distributive)}\\
= x * 1 && \text{(annulment)}\\
= x  && \text{(identity)}\\
\end{align}$$

The ‘other’ absorption law follows from the fact that

$$x+(x*y) = (x+x) * (x+y) = x * (x+y)$$

Comment: Thank you so much , but what do you mean by "if you believe in"

Comment: I just mean ‘if you already agree that these statements are true’. When you prove something, you have to start somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Well, as you haven't given any context, there are two layers in axiomatic systems, syntax and semantics. For instance, in lattices, the absorption laws are often part of the axiomatic system. Then if you assign meaning/semantics to the logical formulas, the laws should be tautologies (evident).

Same here, if you have given the variables a range (universe) and assigned meaning to the operators, the laws should be provable to hold. This is called correctness.

Here $x\vee (x\wedge y)$ is evaluated to true if $x$ is true. Same holds for the r.h.s. $x$.

If $x$ is false, $x\vee (x\wedge y)$ is evaluated to false. Same holds for the r.h.s. $x$.

Comment: Oh thank you so much , now I know the basis of my question rather than following the theorems . It is a very good explanation.